# App crashed when use deep link

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework, deep-linking

I use deep link in an app built with Ionic on Android. When i click on the link, the app opens but crashed just one second after. How could i debug this problem ?

This is the intent code in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.pipp.deeplinks.LinkActivity" android:theme="@android:style/    Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:host="pipp.app.com" android:pathPrefix="/news" android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:host="actionnaires" android:scheme="pipp" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Thanks !

**Update**

By using Android Studio, i have the following logs:

> 10-13 11:10:24.633 20844-20844/com.pipp.actionnaires E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                           Process: com.pipp.actionnaires, PID: 20844
>                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.pipp.actionnaires/com.pipp.deeplinks.LinkActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.pipp.deeplinks.LinkActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.pipp.actionnaires-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.pipp.actionnaires-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.pipp.deeplinks.LinkActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.pipp.actionnaires-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.pipp.actionnaires-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                                               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>                                                                               Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pipp.deeplinks.LinkActivity
>                                                                               at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                                               at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>                                                                               at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>                                                                               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>                                                                                       ... 12 more
>                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available

Comment: Paste the corresponding logcat trace

Comment: you can debugg with android studio... and find error..

Comment: Thanks, i updated my question with error. Could you please tell me how to resolve it ?

Comment: It's a class not found exception, so basically ListActivity class is not present in the dex file. Try not to shrink code while building apks or just add proguard rules if you are not using R8.

Answer (score 0):

You're running from Eclipse or the Android application studio? If `ionic run android` application, you can debug from `chrome://inspect/#devices` to the device you have connected to your computer.

Comment: Yes, i use "ionic run android" and i have only one second. It's not enough to see what happens.